# Proving that the antiderivative of $\operatorname{sech}^2$ is $\operatorname{tanh}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I just had this question on the exams. I tried many ways but didn't figure it out. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To check it just write down the definition of $\text{sech }^2$ and differentiate.

Comment: @EthanBolker: the definition of $\tanh$ and differentiate.

Comment: But it's like cheating , we didn't suppose to know that the result will be tanh

Comment: Or you could differentiate $\tanh(x) +c$, then rewrite all the steps backwards.
We won't tell on you. ;)

Comment: Is there anyway to prove it by the other way ? just calculate directly a primitive ? because i don't think taking the result and differentiate is the way to do on an exam

Comment: If you are told what the antiderivative is and asked to show that it is indeed the antiderivative then there is nothing wrong with differentiating. If you are not told the answer and are asked to find the antiderivative, then that is a completely different question.

Comment: yeah a i said we didn't suppose to know it and the answer was not given , so the question is if there's a way to calculate it directly

Comment: If you knew that anti-derivative of sec^2 is tan for real arguments, then substitute $x \rightarrow ix $  converting to corresponding hyperbolic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer could use substitution $t=\tanh x \Rightarrow \cosh^2 x=\frac{1}{1-t^2}; dx=\frac{dt}{1-t^2}\Rightarrow$ 
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\cosh^2x}=\int dt= t+C=\tanh x +C.
$$

However by careful reading one notes that the derivation just replaces the preknowledge of the derivative of $\tanh x$ with in fact equivalent preknowledge of the derivative of ${\rm arctanh}\, x$.

Therefore it is preferrable to choose another way which uses only derivatives of logarithmic and power functions: 
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\cosh^2x}=\int\frac{4dx}{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}\stackrel{e^x\mapsto u}=
\int\frac{4}{(u+u^{-1})^2}\frac{du}{u}=\int\frac{4udu}{(u^2+1)^2}\\
=-\frac{2}{u^2+1}+(1+C)=\frac{u^2-1}{u^2+1}+C=\frac{u-u^{-1}}{u+u^{-1}}+C
\stackrel{u\mapsto e^x}=\tanh x +C.
$$

Comment: Hyperbolic functions…

Comment: @Rócherz Thank you for noting the mistake. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @kingeuler You're welcome. Please read the revised version of the answer.